# Rails: Setting Facebook Site URL and App Domains for OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, omniauth

Using Rails OmniAuth on Facebook, there is a very subtle issue that I need to fix.
My app is on Heroku and its default domain is `myapp.herokuapp.com` (suppose). I have my personal domain called `hello.com`, and whenever a user goes to hello.com, he is "forwarded" to myapp.herokuapp.com.

On Facebook dev center, there are `App Domains` field and `Site URL` field. I thought I had to put myapp.herokuapp.com into Site URL, and hello.com into App Domains, but it didn't let me.

`"hello.com" must be derived from one of: Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL.`

So I just left App domains blank.

Everything seemed to work fine except for one thing. OmniAuth works fine when I go to my website through myapp.herokuapp.com. But when I go through hello.com, there is one little problem. **When I'm not logged in Facebook already, it does not redirect me to the Facebook Log in page.** So when I click on the login button, it loads for a few seconds but nothing happens (because it's supposed to redirect me to the facebook website to log in there first but it just doesn't) However, when I'm already logged in Facebook, it works fine.

I'm not sure what the problem is. My guesses:

1. I'm setting App Domains & Site URL wrong.
2. I did not set DNS yet. Heroku tells me I have to set the DNS to point to my domain, but I'm not sure what that means as I've never dealt with this. Right now, my personal domain, hello.com is simply forwarding to myapp.herokuapp.com. Is this what's causing the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set DNS, but just forwarded my herokuapp url to my custom domain. Instead of "forwarding," you should set your DNS if you are having a similar problem.